# Unable to read Unix server path for resource property Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, unix, spring-batch

Please help on configuring the resource path for unix location path in SPRING batch. Its working fine when tried in Windows machine.

Property configured in properties file.
location=//home/dir/file.txt

XML Configuration:

```
<bean id="diDeactivateReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
        <property name="resource"
            value="**file:${location}**" />
        <property name="lineMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                <property name="lineTokenizer">
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FixedLengthTokenizer">
                        <property name="names" value="${column.names}" />
                        <property name="columns" value="${column.position}" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                    <bean class="org.test.TestMapper" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode): class path resource [//home/dir/file.txt]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doOpen(FlatFileItemReader.java:250)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:134)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: It looks like it is searching it in classpath ... what are the `*` around `file:${location}` ? And why does a file system path begin with `//` ?

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood it probably uses UrlResource, there's [tutorial](http://simplespringtutorial.com/resourceinjection.html) on how to specify file path. Since you're working on linux machine four consecutive "/" will be necessary.

```
resource = new UrlResource("file:////home/dir/file.txt");
```

For why there's so many slashes are needed refer to URL [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html?is-external=true#URL%28java.lang.String%29):

```
<scheme>://<authority><path>?<query>#<fragment>
```

> If the spec's path component begins with a slash character "/" then
>   the path is treated as absolute and the spec path replaces the context
>   path.

hence third "/" specifies that the path is absolute and "/home/dir/file.txt" is the path itself.